# How is my variable not defined?

Tags: python

Currently, what I have is

```
ntries = 0
def test_guess(code,guess):
    if guess == code:
        return True
        ntries += 1
    else:
        return False
        blackpegs = 0
        whitepegs = 0
        code_remainder = ''
        guess_remainder = ''
        ntries += 1
        for x, y in zip(code,guess):
            if x==y:
                blackpegs += 1
            elif not x==y:
                code_remainder += x
                guess_remainder += y
                for i in guess_remainder:
                    if code_remander.find(i) != -1: #if i is found in the remainder of the code
                        whitepegs += 1
                        code_remainder = code_remainder.replace(i, 'X', 1)
        return code_remainder
        return guess_remainder
        return blackpegs
        return whitepegs
```

Right below, I have

```
if test_guess(code,guess)==True:
    print 'You won!"
elif test_guess(code,guess)==False:
    print 'Not quite. You get',blackpegs,'black pegs,',whitepegs,'white pegs.'
```

`blackpegs` in my final print statement keeps coming up as undefined. Why is it not set to be equal to the blackpegs counter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if guess == code:
    return True
    ntries += 1
```

if your guess == code, then return true, next step can't be executed!

Comment: Hey, would you mind elaborating on this? My code kind of assumes that the user will not be able to guess the code (thus, guess != code) which leads the program to execute the else clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one return statement.

```
return code_reminder
```

Causes the function to immediately exit. You will want to do something like

```
return code_remainder, guess_remainder, blackpegs, whitepegs
```

and then when you call the function, use:

```
code_remainder, guess_remainder, blackpegs, whitepegs = test_guess(code,guess)
```

### General Tip:

Variables/references declared within a function only exist within that function. You will need to explicitly return those variables/references if you want to use them outside of the function. Of course there are also some exceptions to this rule, but it is best that you stick to this method for now.

Comment: This might be a different issue, but how do I get it to print the blackpegs? Every time I test out the code in interpreter (i.e. print test_guess('coke','code')), it only prints False?

Answer (score 0):

`blackpegs` doesn't have a value unless the else statement is reached.  i.e. `if guess == code`, `blackpeg` is not defined.

It needs to be set to zero before the if else statements or otherwise addressed prior to being called in the `return` statement.